# IE onPaste event using JavaScript not HTML

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

It seems that the only way to add an `onPaste` event to an input element is to use HTML:

```
<textarea id="text_area" onpaste="on_paste" />
```

rather than being able to attach the event handler using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('text_area').onPaste = function() { alert('I iz in ur textbox, pasting some text') };
```

The MSDN website says you can only add event handlers for `onPaste` using jscript or HTML, but I want to do it in JavaScript. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: jScript is JavaScript - it's just what Microsoft calls its implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try lowercase:

```
document.getElementById('text_area').onpaste = ...
```

Comment: I thought I'd tried this and it didn't work... Your answer prompted me to try again, and it did work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is down to capitalisation, you want:

```
document.getElementById('text_area').onpaste = function() { alert('I iz in ur textbox, pasting some text') };
```