# How can I enter only numbers in TextBox using JavaScript without disable right click?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, dom-events

I want to allow numbers only to be allowed for a textbox and I already do it `onkeydown` event by allow only numbers and prevent <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> but I have two problems :

1. if I make right click then paste so any char can be entered and I want a solution without disable right click by `oncontextmenu="return false;"`
2. if I drag and drop any text it will be entered

Is there any solution that can work in all browsers without problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just filter out the non numeric chars in the onchange event of your textbox and set it back to the textbox.

Comment: this will allow to enter any char as change event fired after textbox lose focus ... what i need is to not allow user to enter other than number

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onpaste` event. You will be able to catch whenever something is pasted.
You can refer to [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446025/how-can-i-know-user-is-typing-or-pasting/2446044#2446044) regarding `onpaste` event.

Comment: In that case you have to handle onchange event as Ovidiu said.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used jquery for this. Here's the code. Include your jquery file in your html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Include this script in your html.

```
<script>
$('#phoneNum').keypress(function(e) {
    var a = [];
    var k = e.which;

    for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
        a.push(i);

    if (!(a.indexOf(k)>=0))
    {
        if(k != 45){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

This is what your input will look like.  phoneNume being the id.

```
<input type="tel" id="phoneNum" />
```