# HTML: onpaste="doSomething();" as invalid attribute

Tags: html, onpaste

I am checking my HTML code with Amaya.

I have an error on this line:

```
<input style="vertical-align:bottom;" type="text" id="doi_id" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) return false;" onpaste="parsePIIfromDOI();"/>
```

And for the onpaste, I am getting "Invalid attribute "onpaste"(removed when saving)" error.

I don't know why? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What is the onpaste? AFAIK onpaste event is not available in html

Comment: Maybe because `onpaste` is an invalid HTML attribute?

Comment: @Milos which browser are you using ?? And onpaste is valid see this http://jsfiddle.net/TgY6B/1/

Comment: @Harry, The onpaste event will be called vhen pasting something in th texbox for example. For me in works in mozilla but the Amaya shows me an error.

Comment: @Stefan, why then the onpaste works on Mozilla, and also in the 2yogi-s example ?

Comment: @yogi, thank you for the example. for me, it works with Mozilla. I don't know if I should keep it like that or not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/extended-event-attributes/onpaste

"Non-standard event defined by Microsoft for use in Internet Explorer. May work in some other browsers but cannot be reliably used. Compatibility for this non-standard attribute not tested."

Comment: Thank you for the info Stefan, do you think I should use this method or not? For the mment, works with mozilla and also IE. I don't know for the others.

Comment: I think is fine, on this link: http://codebits.glennjones.net/editing/getclipboarddata.htm we can see that only opera does not support the onpaste attribute.

Comment: @Milos: Google Analytics tells me that about 1% of my website visitors use Opera.  I suspect it will be the same for your site.  If you are happy with those visitors not having this functionality then you can use it.  But you might also consider using jQuery to bind the onpaste event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237254/how-do-you-handle-oncut-oncopy-and-onpaste-in-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686995/jquery-catch-paste-input/1503425#1503425

Comment: Thank you Stefan, In fact, the page I am creating is for internal use and will be accessed only by some known members I can control (access, browsers etc.). I think that it should be fine for the moment. thank you very much for the jQuerry idea. I will take a look on it.

Comment: @Milos: You are welcome.  Actually 'normal' javascript (not jQuery) also seems very simple: http://stackoverflow.com/a/546942/888177

Answer (score 3):

The Amaya editor performs a syntax check using a document type definition, and its built-in repertoire includes only doctypes that do not allow the `onpaste` attribute. That’s why you get the error message.

There’s probably no way around this message in Amaya. You can use Tools → Change doctype → Remove the doctype or, better, manually change, in Show Source mode, the doctype declaration to `<!doctype html>`, the HTML5 doctype. But Amaya still keeps checking against the specification it regards as the correct one.

Amaya is an editor (and a testbed browser), not a checker. Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check your syntax. Then you can use `<!doctype html>` to specify HTML5. Beware that HTML5 has some oddities, and contrary to popular misconceptions, it is not a pure extension of HTML 4.01. And apparently because Amaya decides to remove the attribute, you would need to use a different editor.

Whether `onpaste` is useful and safe to use is a different question.

Update (July 2018): Over the years that have passed, `onpaste` has not become part of official HTML, so a validator issues an error message about it. Yet, support appears to appear e.g. in Chrome. If you need to avoid validation errors (or your editor removes an `onpaste` attribute), use JavaScript to assign a value to the `onpaste` property of the element node instead of using an attribute in HTML markup.