# onpaste calling a function javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ext.net, onpaste

I am trying to call a function when something is pasted into a field.
Because I am using ext.net, I can not hardcode the function into the `onpaste`. This is why I am setting it from js.

```
$('#HtmlEditorFDEdit-inputCmp-iframeEl').contents().find("body").attr("onpaste", "alert('you pasted');");
```

This works, however I would like to call a function `myFunction` instead of alerting.

The following gives me a `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`

```
$('#HtmlEditorFDEdit-inputCmp-iframeEl').contents().find("body").attr("onpaste", "myFunction();");
```

I tried moving the function around; from the bottom to the top of the external js file.

I am not even able to the following; (text is blank)

```
var text="asd";
$('#HtmlEditorFDEdit-inputCmp-iframeEl').contents().find("body").attr("onpaste", "alert(text);");
```

Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: seems that duplicated by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367417/html-onpaste-dosomething-as-invalid-attribute

Comment: @AlexFilatov I saw that post but believe it is wrong. according to many sites, onpaste is supported by all major browsers [w3](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpaste.asp)